# Continuity of functions

Tags: functions, continuity

If the value of my answer  when I compute the limit of a function as it tends to c is 0. Not infinity. Is it then continuous?

That is the limit as $x$ tends to $90$ in the function
 $f(x) = \cos (x)$

The answer of the above is 0, is the function continuous at 90? Thanks

**Edit:** 
Please determine the continuity or otherwise of $$f(x) = \frac{x-36}{\sqrt x - 36}$$ at the point x = 36.

Comment: You want to say, I suppose,  "as $x$ tends to $90^\circ$". Yes, the function is continuous at $x=90^\circ$, since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow90^\circ}\cos(x)=0=\cos(90^\circ)$.

Comment: Do you really mean $$\frac{x-36}{\sqrt{x}-36}\ ?$$ Or do you mean $$\frac{x-36}{\sqrt{x}-6}\ ?$$

Comment: @Mob: If you add material to the question that *substantially* changes the question, then please indicate so explicitly.

Comment: The former. Just how it is in the question.

Answer (score 7):

A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if three things happen:

1. The function is *defined* at $c$.
2. The limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to c$ exists.
3. The value of the function at $c$ equals the value of the limit:
   $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = f(c).$$

So just from "the limit of a function as it tends to $c$ is $0$" you cannot tell whether the function is continuous or not: you need the *value* of the function at $c$ to also be $0$ to be able to conclude that.

In the special case of $f(x) = \cos(x)$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (measuring in radians):

1. $f(x)$ *is* defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
2. The limit of $\cos(x)$ as $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}$ exists:
   $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x = 0.$$
3. The value of the limit agrees with the value of the function, since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$. Since
   $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = f(0),$$
   **then** you can conclude that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

That is: it's not just the numerical value of the limit that matters, it is whether that numerical value *agrees* with the value of the function at that point that matters.

---

To the new question: the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x-36}{\sqrt{x}-36}.$$

At $x=36$, the function *is* defined, with value $0$. The limit of the function can be computed using limit laws, since $\sqrt{x}$ *is* continuous at $36$. We get:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 36}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to36}\frac{x-36}{\sqrt{x}-36} 
\\
&= \frac{\lim_{x\to 36}(x-36)}{\lim\limits_{x\to36}(\sqrt{x}-36)}\\
&= \frac{36-36}{\sqrt{36}-36} = \frac{0}{-30} = 0.
\end{align*}$$
Since $f(x)$ is defined at $36$, has a limit as $x\to 36$, and the value of the limit equals the value of the function, then the function *is* continuous at $x=36$.

If you meant $f(x) = \dfrac{x-36}{\sqrt{x}-6}$, then this function is **not** continuous at $x=36$, because it is not *defined* at $x=36$.

Comment: @ Arturo. Very nice, +1

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question